# Is there a unique insphere for an irregular triangular bipyramid?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I know that there is a unique incircle for a triangle, and how to calculate it.

My intuition tells me that there would be an analogous sphere for a triangular bipyramid, but I am struggling to use the logic for calculating it in a triangle for calculating it in an irregular triangular bipyramid.

Is there a known solution?

---

For those interested, this would be valuable to me in display calibration for a visual neuroscience experiment.

Specifically, for working out the set colours that are equal in colour difference relative to a single point, when taking both chromaticity and luminance into account, for a screen with primaries of given XYZ tristimulus values, where the goal is maximising the colour difference (the radius of the sphere).

Comment: Sticking with two dimensions, consider an arbitrary quadrilateral w/diagonal $AB$ and other pts $P$ & $Q$. Triangles $PAB$ & $QAB$ have unique incircles; say, w/incenters $P'$ & $Q'$. Line $PP'$ contains all pts equidistant from side-lines $PA$ & $PB$; likewise, $QQ'$. An incenter of the full quad must (1) lie on both lines, and (2) have the same distance from the $P$ side-lines & the $Q$ side-lines. Condition (1) fails if the lines are parallel; (2) isn't guaranteed, either; thus, not all quads have an incircle. A similar argument applies to bipyramids; but w/them, (1) fails more easily.

Comment: The analog of triangles in 3D is the tetrahedron; the underlying concept is the [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).  There are indeed well known formulas for insphere (inradius) and circumsphere (circumradius) for a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Inradius).  However, for visualization, you really should avoid varying luminance too much; this changes your original problem into *distributing* your point colors within in the chromaticity (Cb,Cr) plane. [*]

Comment: [*] If the colors are related to density or similar values in a diagram, each pair of consecutive colors should vary a constant amount.  You can achieve this by putting a curve on the chromaticity plane (Cr-Cb plane), and sampling the colors at constant intervals along the curve, so that the samples are also more or less regularly distributed in the plane.  [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is one I've used before (taking samples at the vertices/corners), but it gives a specific number of point colors (depending on number of iterations).

Comment: You do not have always a such sphere. You can have the sphere touch 4 sides. It is not guaranteed that it will touch (reach or intersect) the fifth side.

Comment: @moti Do you think there is an analytic way to find the location and radius of a sphere with the maximum possible radius, even if it doesn't touch all the sides?

Comment: @DannyGarside given the equation of 4 planes you solve 4 distance equations for the center and the radius.